# What is a packet UDP/TCP?

Tags: c++

Im getting into Winsocks and is there any reference to tell me what a packet is. Like UDP/TCP Packets?

Comment: Can you clarify your question - are you wanting to know about the concept of UDP/TCP packets or are you looking for documentation on the datastructures that represent UDP/TCP packets under Winsock? Or something else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A good starting point for TCP/IP is here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Protocol_Suite, and for UDP here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Datagram_Protocol

In addition, this looks like a pretty good introduction to Winsock in C++: http://www.madwizard.org/programming/tutorials/netcpp/

Answer (score 1):

Google is your friend here.  If anything is available on the internet it is TCP/IP information.

[This](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol) is as good a start as any.  When you get really serious [this](http://www.kohala.com/start/tcpipiv1.html) is as close to a classic text as there is.

Answer (score 1):

A packet is a small "chunk" of data.  Usually when you send data over a network, it cannot go in a complete piece (actually it *could* but networks don't work like that because it's faster to send data in pieces).  It is broken up into [packets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Packet_%28information_technology%29), [segments](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_segment), and [datagrams](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Datagram#Packets_vs._datagrams)

Comment: Great Example but he did better but +1 Loved the diagrams

Answer (score 0):

a packet is small piece of data witch can be transferable over a network.
in it data is packed along with check sum for error checking.
For UDP - you can say it is nothing but broadcasting of messages(Packets) with no acknowledgment.
And For TCP/IP - It is protocol for transferring data over network